# How to define a new cache context for a node

Tags: 8, caching

I am preprocessing a node with some data, i want to define a new cache context  based on this data.

```
function hook_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $variables['change'] = rand(0,5);
}
```

Once i have defined the new context i think i shuold be able to use it as follows.

```
function  hook_entity_build_defaults_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, $view_mode) {
  if($entity->getType() == 'page'){
    $build['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'change';
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find out how to define a brand new cache context based on the data in my preprocess so that i can use it in hook_entity_build_defaults_alter();

Answer (score 6):

You will need to define a cache context in `yourmodule/src/Context`. This will be a class implementing *CacheContextInterface*, as described in the docs [here](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/contexts) (see 'How to recognize, discover and create?).

If you search for `implements CacheContextInterface` in your code base you should be able to see some examples. The class will provide `getContext()` and `getCacheableMetadata()` methods.

Comment: note that you also need to define it as a service, not just the class.