# How to avoid certain variables from being cached?

Tags: 8, caching

I've spent days trying to figure this out and really hope you guys can help me out here.

Let's say, I’ve created a list field on the user entity called `field_render_array` with the options:

- Render array 1
- Render array 2

There is a controller called `RenderArray` which should:

- Return render array 0 if `field_render_array` is not set.
- Return render array 1 if `field_render_array` is equal to `render_array_1`.
- Return render array 2 if `field_render_array` is equal to
  `render_array_2`.

I’ve been trying to achieve this using a controller like:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class RenderArrayController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content() {
    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $field_render_array = $user->get(‘field_render_array’)->value;

    if (!isset($field_render_array)) {
      return array(
        ‘#markup' => ‘You haven’t set your preferred render array.',
      );
    }
    else if ($field_render_array == ‘render_array_1’ ) {
      return array(
        ‘#markup' => ‘Your preferred render array is 1',
      );
    }
    else {
      return array(
        ‘#markup' => ‘Your preferred render array is 2’,
      );
    }
  }

}
```

The problem is that the value of `$field_render_array` is getting cached. This comes across as a bug for end-users as the render array doesn’t immediately change after changing the value of `field_render_array`.

Is it possible to somehow avoid certain variables from being cached or is there another solution to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Google "drupal 8 lazy builder".

Answer (score 3):

If the variables come from the current user, then add this cache context to the build array you return:

```
$build['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';
```

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays for lots of documentation. Note that this means that your controller will possibly have a huge amount of variations, one for each user. If it is not expensive to build, you might want to disable caching completely with #cache max-age = 0. If it is expensive and you have a lot of users, you could make your own cache contexts that doesn't vary by user ID but just by the value of that field. You just need a service, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214144/how-to-define-a-new-cache-context-for-a-node

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I decided to reduce the number of render array's from 3 to 1.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class RenderArrayController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content() {
    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $field_render_array = $user->get('field_render_array')->value;

    if (!isset($field_render_array)) {
      $markup = 'You haven’t set your preferred render array.';
    }
    else if ($field_render_array == 'render_array_1' ) {
      $markup = 'Your preferred render array is 1';
    }
    else {
      $markup = 'Your preferred render array is 2';
    }

    return array(
      '#markup' => $markup,
      '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0],
    );

  }

}
```

As the `field_render_array` can always change, I added `'#cache' => ['max-age' => 0]` to the render array left. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays for more information.